# Gradient of the layers of a loaded neural network in Chainer

Tags: python, deep-learning, pre-trained-model, chainer, vgg-net

I am loading a pre-trained model in Chainer:

```
net=chainer.links.VGG16Layers(pretrained_model='auto')
```

Then, I make a forward pass with some data and add a loss layer:

`acts = net.predict([image]).array
loss=chainer.Variable(np.array(np.sum(np.square(acts-one_hot))))`

Now the question is, how can I make a backward pass and get the gradients of the different layers?

The typical backward method does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get `.grad` of the input image, you have to wrap the input by `chainer.Variable`.
However, `VGGLayers.extract()` does not support inputs of `Variable`, so in this case you should call `.forward()` or its wrapping function `__call__()`.

```
import chainer
from chainer import Variable
from chainer import functions as F
from cv2 import imread
from chainer.links.model.vision import vgg

net = vgg.VGG16Layers(pretrained_model='auto')

# convert raw image (np.ndarray, dtype=uint32) to a batch of Variable(dtype=float32)
img = imread("path/to/image")
img = Variable(vgg.prepare(img))
img = img.reshape((1,) + img.shape)  # (channel, width, height) -> (batch, channel, width, height)

# just call VGG16Layers.forward, which is wrapped by __call__()
prob = net(img)['prob']
intermediate = F.square(prob)
loss = F.sum(intermediate)

# calculate grad
img_grad = chainer.grad([loss], [img])  # returns Variable
print(img_grad.array) # some ndarray
```

Comment: I am not sure if I should ask this here; but why you would need vgg.prepare of img to pass it to net(), but you can pass the image as it is to net.predict()? Aren't they the same method?

And why does vgg.prepare() make a 3x3 table (9 copies) of the given image?

Comment: 1. vgg.prepare is just included in net.predict(). 2.  img.shape == (1440, 1920, 3), vgg.prepare(img).shape == (3, 224, 224). img.dtype == dtype('uint8'), vgg.prepare(img).dtype == dtype('float32'). This is the reason.

Comment: I still don't get why vgg.prepare makes 9 small scaled copies from the given image in a 224x224 image:

If you give it an image like X, it will give you xxx (x is a small scaled version of X)
                                                                      xxx
                                                                      xxx

Comment: No, as is shown in my last comment, it does not give 9 small copies. If you get copies, something is going wrong. It only resizes, scales, and transposes (H, W, C) -> (C, H, W).

Comment: I have asked the question more accurately and attached the input and the output in here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257608/why-does-vgg-prepare-method-create-9-copies-of-the-given-image?noredirect=1#comment93400356_53257608

Answer (score 2):

Point 1.
DO NOT call `VGGLayers.predict()`, which is not for backprop computation.
DO use `VGGLayers.extract()` instead.

Point 2.
DO NOT apply `np.square()` and `np.sum()` directly to `chainer.Variable`.
DO use `F.square()` and `F.sum()` instead for `chainer.Variable`.

Point 3.
Use `loss.backward()` to obtain `.grad` for learnable parameters. (pattern 1)
Use `loss.backward(retain_grad=True)` to obtain `.grad` for all variables. (pattern 2)
Use `chainer.grad()` to obtain `.grad` for a specific variable. (pattern 3)

Code:

```
import chainer
from chainer import functions as F, links as L
from cv2 import imread

net = L.VGG16Layers(pretrained_model='auto')
img = imread("/path/to/img")
prob = net.extract([img], layers=['prob'])['prob']  # NOT predict, which overrides chainer.config['enable_backprop'] as False
intermediate = F.square(prob)
loss = F.sum(intermediate)

# pattern 1:
loss.backward()
print(net.fc8.W.grad)  # some ndarray
print(intermediate.grad)  # None
###########################################
net.cleargrads()
intermediate.grad = None
prob.grad = None
###########################################

# pattern 2:
loss.backward(retain_grad=True)
print(net.fc8.W.grad)  # some ndarray
print(intermediate.grad)  # some ndarray

###########################################
net.cleargrads()
intermediate.grad = None
prob.grad = None
###########################################

# pattern 3:
print(chainer.grad([loss], [net.fc8.W]))  # some ndarray
print(intermediate.grad)  # None
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer Yuki, that works!

Comment: I marked solved, but because of my less than 15 reputations can not upvote yet.

Comment: How can I get the input layer (image) gradient? Because the VGG does not have such a layer.

Comment: Thanks for marking solved! I added another answer to get the input image. This is a little bit tricky, so if you have a question, don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: I am not sure that I get the difference between extract and predict. What does predict has to do with backdrop? Because intuitively it should just make a forward pass.

Comment: Would you please explain the difference between the three patterns?

Comment: `predict` disables backprop. No backpropagation is enabled in this function.
In `extract`, back propagation is enables. However, it contains `vgg.prepare` in it, and it does not accept input of `Variable`.`__call__` is the same to  `forward`, it enables backprop and accept `Variable`, but does not accept `uint8` input. It only accepts input preprocessed to suit to the input of ImageNet.