# Why does vgg.prepare() method create 9 copies of the given image?

Tags: python, image, pre-trained-model, chainer, vgg-net

I get this result when I apply vgg.prepare() to the following image:[image: Input]

I use this line of code:

```
Image.fromarray(np.uint8(vgg.prepare(pep).reshape(224,224,3)))
```

And get an image which is combined of 9 copies of the given image:

[image: Output]

Comment: Can you share how did you instantiate `vgg` and `pep`?

Comment: `pep=Image.open("/Users/macintosh/Desktop/Code/sngan_projection-master/images/red_pepper.jpg")`

and 

`from chainer.links.model.vision import vgg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got what you did...
the only mistake is `.reshape`.

Because the image is *transposed*, not *reshaped*, you have to *re-transpose* to restore the original image.

```
pep = pep.transpose((1, 2, 0))  # transpose
pep += [103.939, 116.779, 123.68]  # un-normalize
pep = pep.astype(np.uint8)  # revert dtype
pep = np.flip(pep, axis=2)  # BGR -> RGB
PIL_image = Image.fromarray(pep)  # finally got the original!
```